# how to pass `id` and `object` to an angular service

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, observable

Angular 8, Django 3. On the backend I am using `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`. On the Angular side I have a service that is using an `id` field taken from the `ActivatedRoute` to lookup a `Restaurant` model. All of that works fine.

What I want to do is once I have made changes to the model, I want to submit those updates to the `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` view. But I dont know how to pass both the new `Restaurant` object (`initial_restaurant`) AND the `id` parameter so the `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` knows which `Restaurant` to update...

I think i will definitely need to make another service function that is an `http.post` or `http.patch`, but I dont know how to both send the `id` to the urls.py and the object at the same time..

**DjangoView**

```
class RestaurantEdit(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = RestaurantEditSerializer
    queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()
```

**RestaurantEditComponent**

```
  initial_restaurant: RestaurantEdit
  id:string

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
    this.get_restaurant(this.id)
    console.log(this.initial_restaurant)
  }

  get_restaurant(id){
    this.restaurantservice.restaurantedit(id).subscribe(restaurant => this.initial_restaurant = restaurant)
  }

  savechanges(id, initial_restaurant){
    this.restaurantservice.restaurantedit(id, initial_restaurant).subscribe()
  }

}
```

- i tried passing two variables but thats definitely not correct..

**html**

```
<p>Edit Restaurant </p>
<div *ngIf = "initial_restaurant">
    <input type="text"  id="name" required 
    [(ngModel)]="initial_restaurant.name" /><br>
    <input type="text"  id="food" required 
    [(ngModel)]="initial_restaurant.food" /><br>
    <button (click)="savechanges(initial_restaurant)">Save Changes</button>
</div>
```

**service**

```
restaurantedit(id): Observable<Restaurant>{
  return this.http.get<Restaurant>(this.restauranteditUrl+'/'+id)
}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'restaurantedit/<int:pk>', RestaurantEdit.as_view(), name='restaurantedit')
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with Django, but it appears the issue is likely in the service method you are calling.
Here you have a method taking just an id

```
restaurantedit(id): Observable<Restaurant>{
  return this.http.get<Restaurant>(this.restauranteditUrl+'/'+id)
}
```

But when you call it you pass it both elements

```
  savechanges(id, initial_restaurant){
     this.restaurantservice.restaurantedit(id, initial_restaurant).subscribe()
  }
```

What you likely want to do is set up the method to expect 2 parameters and **include the initial_restraurant object in the body** of the post and use the id as a route parameter for the controller.

something like

```
 restaurantedit(id, restaurant): Observable<Restaurant>{
   return this.http.post<Restaurant>(this.restauranteditUrl+'/'+id, restaurant)
  }
```